# How to construct the Nagel point of a triangle with GeometricScene?

Tags: geometry, synthetic-geometry

Let us consider [the Nagel point of a triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagel_point). According to this article,"There exists an easy construction of the Nagel point. Starting from each vertex of a triangle, it suffices to carry twice the length of the opposite edge. We obtain three lines which concur at the Nagel point". Can it be realized in Mathematica? I make only

```
GeometricScene[{a, b, c}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}]}]
```

It is unclear to me how "to carry twice the length of the opposite edge".

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{a, b, c, s, i,n}, 
{s == TriangleCenter[{a, b, c}, "Centroid"],i == TriangleCenter[{a, b, c}, "Incenter"], n == 3 s - 2 i, 
Point[s], Point[i], Point[n], Triangle[{a, b, c}]}], 1]
```

Addition made by user 64494 for the user's convenience. See [German Wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagel-Punkt) where `Norm[n-s]:2 Norm[s-i]==2:1` is stated.
[image]

Comment: A good code is a commented code. Could you comment your code, giving us more details? In particular. what is your `n`?

Comment: The Wiki article  writes only "The Nagel point, the centroid, and the incenter are collinear on a line called the Nagel line".

Comment: `n` is the nagelpoint. German wiki   and you as OP too, states ` Norm[n-s]:2 Norm[s-i]==2:1`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the relation `n == 2 s - i` implies the relation `n - s == s - i` so the lengths of `n - s` and `s - i` are equal, whereas https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagel-Punkt says this ratio equals $2$.

Comment: I modified `n== 3 s-2 i` in my answer

Comment: Thank you for the fixed error. Can you add the explanation to your answer for its completeness in order to accept the answer? TIA.

Comment: I think my answer is self-explanatory. Feel free to contact me if something is unclear.

Comment: +1. I changed my mind: I prefer the @cvgmt 's answer because the one uses only the definition.

Answer (score 5):

Here we don't provide an updated answer since @user64494 always make unreasonable demands.

```
int = 6;
RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c, i, tc, Tc, ta, Ta, tb, Tb, 
   n}, {i == RegionCentroid@Insphere[{a, b, c}], 
   GeometricAssertion[Triangle[{a, b, c}], "Counterclockwise"], 
   RegionMember[Line[{a, b}], tc], 
   RegionMember[Insphere[{a, b, c}], tc], tc - a == b - Tc, 
   RegionMember[Line[{b, c}], ta], 
   RegionMember[Insphere[{a, b, c}], ta], ta - b == c - Ta, 
   RegionMember[Line[{c, a}], tb], 
   RegionMember[Insphere[{a, b, c}], tb], tb - c == a - Tb, 
   RegionMember[Line[{a, Ta}], n], RegionMember[Line[{b, Tb}], n], 
   RegionMember[Line[{c, Tc}], n]}], RandomSeeding -> int]
```

[image]

```
int=39;
RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{{a, b, c, Ia, Ta, Ib, Tb, Ic, Tc, n}, {ra, rb, rc}},
  {GeometricAssertion[Triangle[{a, b, c}], "Counterclockwise"],
   PlanarAngle[b -> {Ia, c}] == (π - PlanarAngle[b -> {c, a}])/2,
   PlanarAngle[c -> {b, Ia}] == (π - PlanarAngle[c -> {a, b}])/2,
   GeometricAssertion[{Circle[Ia, ra], Line[{b, c}]}, {"Tangent", Ta}],
   PlanarAngle[c -> {Ib, a}] == (π - PlanarAngle[c -> {a, b}])/2,
   PlanarAngle[a -> {c, Ib}] == (π - PlanarAngle[a -> {b, c}])/2,
   GeometricAssertion[{Circle[Ib, rb], Line[{c, a}]}, {"Tangent", Tb}],
   PlanarAngle[a -> {Ic, b}] == (π - PlanarAngle[a -> {b, c}])/2,
   PlanarAngle[b -> {a, Ic}] == (π - PlanarAngle[b -> {c, a}])/2,
   GeometricAssertion[{Circle[Ic, rc], Line[{a, b}]}, {"Tangent", Tc}],
   Line[{a, n, Ta}], Line[{b, n, Tb}], Line[{c, n, Tc}]
   }], RandomSeeding -> int]
```

[image]

```
int = 13;
RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{a, b, c, i, Ta, Tb, Tc, Ia, Ib, Ic, n},
  {GeometricAssertion[Triangle[{a, b, c}], "Counterclockwise"],
   i == TriangleCenter[{a, b, c}, "Incenter"],
   PlanarAngle[a -> {i, Ib}] == \[Pi]/2,
   PlanarAngle[b -> {i, Ic}] == \[Pi]/2,
   PlanarAngle[c -> {i, Ia}] == \[Pi]/2,
   Line[{Ib, a, Ic}], Line[{Ic, b, Ia}], Line[{Ia, c, Ib}],
   PlanarAngle[Ta -> {b, Ia}] = \[Pi]/2,
   PlanarAngle[Tb -> {c, Ib}] = \[Pi]/2,
   PlanarAngle[Tc -> {a, Ic}] = \[Pi]/2,
   RegionMember[Line[{a, b}], Tc],
   RegionMember[Line[{b, c}], Ta],
   RegionMember[Line[{c, a}], Tb],
   Line[{a, n, Ta}], Line[{b, n, Tb}], Line[{c, n, Tc}]}], 
 RandomSeeding -> int]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. A good work. Can you shortly comment your code in order to accept your answer?  A good code is a commented code.

Comment: BTW, [Russian Wik](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Точка_Нагеля)i says there are four Nagel points.

Comment: If unnecessary `i == RegionCentroid@Insphere[{a, b, c}]` is omitted, then `RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c, ab, ba, bc, cb, ca, ac, 
   n}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], RegionMember[Line[{a, b}], ab], 
   RegionMember[Insphere[{a, b, c}], ab], ba - b == a - ab, 
   RegionMember[Line[{b, c}], bc], 
   RegionMember[Insphere[{a, b, c}], bc], bc - b == c - cb, 
   RegionMember[Line[{c, a}], ca], 
   RegionMember[Insphere[{a, b, c}], ca], ca - c == a - ac, 
   RegionMember[Line[{a, cb}], n], RegionMember[Line[{b, ac}], n], 
   RegionMember[Line[{c, ba}], n]}]]` produces an unclear result

Comment: @user64494  For example `RandomInstance[...,RandomSeeding -> 11]`

Comment: cvgmt(@ does not work): Thank you, `RandomSeeding -> 11` does work. I repeat can you extend the  comment to your  code to be understandable to an average user? In particular, what do `RegionMember` and `RandomSeed->11` do?

Comment: For the user's convenience I'd like to comment a simplified code `RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c, ab, ba}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   RegionMember[Line[{a, b}], ab], 
   RegionMember[Insphere[{a, b, c}], ab], ba - b == a - ab}]]`. Here 5 points `{a, b, c, ab, ba}` and a triangle `Triangle[{a, b, c}` are give. Next, `RegionMember[Line[{a, b}], ab]` chooses point `ab` on `Line[{a, b}]`. `RegionMember[Insphere[{a, b, c}], ab]` does the similar, and `ba - b == a - ab` gives the equality of the vectors in the LHS and RHS.

Comment: I don't find the `RandomSeeding -> 11` option in the documentation. In general, the construction of @cvgmt follows the easy construction of the Nagel point from the linked Wiki article.

Comment: I don't understand ungrounded " @user64494 always make unreasonable demands".

Answer (score 3):

```
RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{A,B,C,P},
 {P==With[{a=Norm[B-C],b=Norm[C-A],c=Norm[A-B]},({-a+b+c,a-b+c,a+b-c}/(a+b+c)). {A,B,C}], 
Triangle[{A,B,C}]}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. A good code is a commented code. Do you apply barycentric coordinates?